# How to sqaure an CSS grid-item element? How to set same height as width?

Tags: css, grid, css-grid

I am wondering if it is possible to have a **squared** css grid-item that overstretches (for example) from grid-column 1 to grid-column 5. 
How can I make a square out of this grid item element?

HTML would be something like this:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="squared">
    This blue element should be a square.<br/>
    Same height as width. 
  </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.wrap{
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 20% 20% 20% 20% 20%;
}

.squared{
  background-color: blue;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 5;
}
```

**I have prepared a JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/b8utkf21/

Answer (score -1):

you can use jquery to achieve this. e.x.

```
var cw = $('.squared').width();
$('.wrap').css({'height':cw+'px'});
```

Comment: True. But I would prefer a solution without JavaScript.

Comment: @iMax Because of the way you are using relative widths in a max-width box that is not the width of the viewport, this is about the only way you will find to do this